# d3.v3.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have a mistake and I can not find it, thanks for your help.

My data is called `consumer_complaints.csv`:

```
date_received,product,sub_product,issue,sub_issue,consumer_complaint_narrative,company_public_response,company,state,zipcode,tags,consumer_consent_provided,submitted_via,date_sent_to_company,company_response_to_consumer,timely_response, consumer_disputed,complaint_id
08/30/2013,Mortgage,Other mortgage,Loan modification,collection,foreclosure,U.S. Bancorp,CA,95993,Referral,09/03/2013,Closed with explanation,Yes,Yes,511074
```

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#ff0000", "#00ff00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("consumer_complaints.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

var nested_data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.submitted_via; })
.entries(data);

var subVia = [];
nested_data.forEach(function(d,i){
  var count = 0;
  subVia[i] = d.key;
  d.values.forEach(function(v){
      if(v.consumer_disputed == "Yes")
        count++
  });
  d.dispu = [{name: "Yes",value: count/d.values.length},{name: "No",value: 
  (d.values.length-count)/d.values.length}];
});

  x0.domain(subVia.forEach(function(d,i){ return subVia[i]; }));
  x1.domain(subVia).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(nested_data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.dispu, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Satisfaction");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("transform", subVia.forEach(
        function(d,i) {console.log(subVia[i]); return "translate(" + x0(subVia[i]) + ",0)"; }));

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.dispu; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(subVia.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#ff0000", "#00ff00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("consumer_complaints.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

var nested_data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.submitted_via; })
.entries(data);

var subVia = [];
nested_data.forEach(function(d,i){
  var count = 0;
  subVia[i] = d.key;
  d.values.forEach(function(v){
      if(v.consumer_disputed == "Yes")
        count++
  });
  d.dispu = [{name: "Yes",value: count/d.values.length},{name: "No",value: 
  (d.values.length-count)/d.values.length}];
});

  x0.domain(subVia.forEach(function(d,i){ return subVia[i]; }));
  x1.domain(subVia).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(nested_data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.dispu, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Satisfaction");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("transform", subVia.forEach(
        function(d,i) {console.log(subVia[i]); return "translate(" + x0(subVia[i]) + ",0)"; }));

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.dispu; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.key); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(subVia.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answers.